# Add class to input if entered less than 10 digits in Angular 8

Tags: angular

How can I add an extra class to the input if a user does not enter 10 digits and leave?

Basically, I want to add `class="form-control error"` if the user leaves the input field without entering 10 digits.

```
<input type="text" (keypress)="keyPress($event)" minlength=10 maxlength=10 class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile" name="mobile" [(ngModel)]="profile.mobile" required>

keyPress(event: any) {
    const pattern = /[0-9\+\-\ ]/;
    const inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    if (event.key !== 8 && !pattern.test(inputChar)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you try `<input type="text" (keypress)="keyPress($event)" [ngClass]="{'form-control error' : form.get('inp').touched && form.get('inp').hasError('minlength')}">
`

Comment: This will work assuming you have named the formcontrol as `inp`

Comment: @NicholasK doesn't appear to be using reactive forms.

Comment: form-control error is not a class, it is two classes

Comment: `form-control` is default and already added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use any JavaScript since Angular got its own [form validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation).

- You have to export ngModel to a local template variable with `#mobile="ngModel"`
- Then you coud add your class using [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) by checking if your ngModel is invalid with `[ngClass]="{'error': mobile.invalid && (mobile.dirty || mobile.touched)"`

The following should work (not tested):

```
<input type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile" 
       name="mobile" [(ngModel)]="profile.mobile" required #mobile="ngModel" 
       [ngClass]="{'error': mobile.invalid && (mobile.dirty || mobile.touched)">
```

To make sure that your validation wont be executed on each keypress you could change [ngModels updateOn option](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#properties) from `change` (its default) into `blur` using `[ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"`

Comment: Thank you! It's working but the class `error` is shown while still typing and so the border becomes red as my CSS code is `form-control.error { border: 1px solid red}`. Is there a way to show the class `error` only when I leave the input field?

Comment: Sure :) for this use `[ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"`. With this the validation will start after leaving the focus of the input or after hitting enter.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much. I have been looking online for the last 3+ hours to fix this issue.